# Windows support software could not be saved to the selected drive

Tags: macos, bootcamp

I been installing Windows on my new MacBook Pro 13" 2017 Touchbar (MacOS Sierra) but I have been stuck because I get the error `Windows support software could not be saved to the selected drive` ... I tried installing it using a 16gb USB stick  (MSDOS fat32) and no USB since my MacBook can install Windows even without USB flash drive (as mentioned by apple in their website.) Can someone help me with these problems?

Comment: Did the error occur when trying to install by using the using the Boot Camp Assistant or when your were just using the Boot Camp Assistant to download the Boot Camp Support Software? In other words, did the error occur when you did not use a flash drive or when you tried to use the flash drive?

Comment: Both error occur with or with out flash drive, i tried it only with the use of flash drive since error is still coming out if i dont use flash drive, ( just using my internal drive for installing) but same thing happen,, Error occur when trying to install windows,,when i open BcA, i click continue, then choose the ISO image for windows, then click Install, then it shows downloading software,, after few mins the error occur

Comment: It is possible to install window 10 where the Boot Camp Assistant is only used to downloading the Boot Camp Support Software.  Look for the "Action" pulldown on the Boot Camp Assistant menu bar. On my Mac, these files were downloaded to the ~/WindowsSupport directory. If you  can successfully download this software, I can post instructions for finishing the installation of Windows 10 without further use of the Boot Camp Assistant. If you have already tried this and failed, then I probably can not help you further.

Comment: I already tried it several times,, but still the error shows up,, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

**Cause**

Apple allows Windows Installation, by first copying the entire ISO into a temporary storage area.  Most of the time it works, because there is enough space available.

When we use a larger ISO, like the 32-bit + 64-bit Windows ISO, it requires about 6.5 GB just for the storage, let alone uncompressed files usage.  Apple tried to download Windows support software onto that partition.  This is where the issue happens.  The package requires at least 1 GB, and it would not get it because of the ISO.

**Solution**

- Use the 64-bit ISO (3.5GB) instead of the 32-bit + 64-bit Windows ISO for a x64 MacBook (all current generation ones)
- Use the 32-bit ISO (3.5GB) instead of the 32-bit + 64-bit Windows ISO for a x86 MacBook (2011 etc.)